# Calculator: Terminate program if the mathematical operation is invalid

Tags: python, calculator

I am very new to coding in general and have started learning python just very recently. I am trying to make a simple calculator. However, I am experiencing a problem whereas I want it to terminate the program if the mathematical operation that the user has input is invalid. However, in my case it simply proceeds with the program.

Here is a part of my code

```
if use_calculator.lower() == "yes":
    print("That's great to hear, " + name + " please proceed")
    operation = input("What mathematical operation would you like to execute? ")
    num1 = float(input("Please input a number: "))
    num2 = float(input("Please input another number: "))
    if operation.lower() == "+" or "addition":
        print(num1 + num2)
    elif operation.lower() == "-" or "subtraction":
        print(num1 - num2)
    elif operation.lower() == "division" or "/":
        print(num1 / num2)
    elif operation.lower() ==  "multiplication" or "*" or "x":
        print(num1 * num2)
    else:
        exit()
else:
    print("That is very sad to hear, " + name)
```

Comment: Replace `operation.lower() == "+" or "addition":` with `operation.lower() in ("+", "addition"):` and do the same for other ops. "or" doesn't join a list together, it only tests whether either of two values are truthy and non-empty strings are truthy

Answer (score 1):

Non-empty strings in Python are *truthy*. This means they will always evaluate to `True` when used in an if-statement. This can be seen after the `or` for your if blocks. Instead, you should check if the `operation.lower()` is contained in a set for every if statement you have like so:

```
if operation.lower() in ("+", "addition"):
    ....
```